# APEX Trigger update issue on previously related record

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an Object called Statement which has numeric field Total Cost.
I have an Object called Expense which has lookup relationship to object Statement with numeric field Cost.

I have two statement records A and B.

I have two records in Expense Object C and D:

C: Cost = 5, Statement = A

D: Cost = 7, Statement = A

My APEX trigger on Expense Object calculates total cost and updates related statement to updated Expense Object.
So A statement Total Cost will be 12.

Issue is, when I go to Expense C and change Statement from A to B.

B is going to be updated with Total Cost = 5

Problem is that A Statement Total Cost is still going to have 12 and is not going to be updated to 7.

Does not look that before update is going to solve my issue.
Also Trigger.old when record is updated is. not going to work either.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Your code needs to update both the 'winning' and 'losing' parent records (rather than just the 'winning' record). If you're not sure how to manage that (and even if you are), then you should consider using [Andrew Fawcett's DLRS tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the statement value on new expense has changed from old expense, if yes then you have a couple of options.

```
if(newExpense.Statement__c != oldExpense.Statement__c)
```

I would probably select all expense records related to the old statement, loop through them adding the Cost__c fields together and include the new value on a new Statement record for update.

```
Statement__c s = new Statement__c(Id = oldExpense.Statement__c, Total_Cost__c = newlyCalculatedCost);
```

Then include the statement object in the list of statements you are already updating.

If the data model allows of course this could be handled by roll-up summary fields rather than calculated fields.